# jQuery UI -- Draggable options in bind function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

How can I use the jQuery UI draggable options in a "bind" function? Using the standard `draggable()` function doesn't work with what I want to do.

Thanks!

```
$('a#dragthis')
    .bind('dragstart', function(e) {
        isDragging = true;
    })
    .bind('drag', function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        console.log(x + "|" + y);
        motivationIsWorking(x, y);
    })
    .bind('dragend', function(e) {
        isDragging = false;
        motivationStopped();
        unmotivateUser();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draggable has callback functions to do exactly what you are looking for:

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

So instead of this

```
.bind('dragend', function(e) {
    isDragging = false;
    motivationStopped();
    unmotivateUser();
});
```

do this

```
$(element).draggable({
    stop:function( event, ui ) {
        isDragging = false;
        motivationStart();
        remotivateUser();
    }
});
```